# Why are my pomegranate seeds white?

Tags: seeds, pomegranate

I just seeded a pomegranate, and instead of red / deep pink seeds, the seeds are pale pink / white. What does this mean? Are they ok to eat?

Comment: A quick Google search for "white pomegranate" seems to show that the color depends on the specific pomegranate cultivar.

Comment: I have had two pomegranate trees in our AZ yard for 20+ years. Until about 5 years ago the seeds were always big, red and juicy. Now they are white, smaller, not as juicy... but the flavor is still good. We planted 9 more trees (as a privacy hedge) 3 years ago and the fruit from these trees is also white. Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some [pomegranate varieties](http://www.hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/morton/pomegranate.html) produce pink or white seeds so yours sounds perfectly normal. I have had white seeds and they are as delicious as the red ones. Go for it.

Answer (score 5):

My tree has always made very nice red seeds. But over the past couple of years they have been getting lighter. Now they are clear white or slightly pink.

It has been very warm in the later months, and the leaves of the tree are staying on longer.  I think the climate is the main factor. As with the person from AZ, they appear to get redder as the leaves fall from the chill.

Unfortunately the birds and other creatures are well trained to come to the tree by this time and feast.

They are tastie but not pretty and not as tart.

Comment: I wonder if it could be that the older the tree, the less red in the seeds?

Answer (score 2):

I just opened one up from the tree in my yard.  I was sad when I found white seeds on the inside. I was under the impression the seeds were red. The tree was here when I moved here so this fruit is a new experience for me. I tasted the white seeds and was surprised at the sweet flavor.  Not tart in taste at all, that's what I was expecting from the google search I did. Only one of the pomegranates on the tree was split open so I am thinking I will watch carefully and give them a smidge longer, it's September and from what I read October is a good month for the fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a different variety of pomegranate. They are good, but taste sweeter than the deep red seeds, which have a great tart flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Got pomegranate with pale pink/white seed. I was surprised when i first opened it because i have been always getting the dark red seed varity.  I thought i got a bad fruit.  After I taste it, those pale pink/white seed taste sweeter and it is less tart than the drak red varity.  It is also more juicy.  I LOVED it!!

Answer (score 0):

i am ali agricultur ellit from Iran as you know pomegranate is from Iran originaly. we had the same problem in Iran and my pomegranate s seeds 
were pale pink and white and part of its are black 
i think the reason of this problem was blend of fertilizing
and solar direct radation and clima alter but in iran we used biostimulant such as megafol from valagro co during the growth and use  great fertilizing treatment for increase the quality 
fingers crossed

Answer (score -1):

Thats normal it is that colour Pale Pink white... depends which place on the pomegranate that particular seed is from...they are totally fine to eat, you just need know that they are a different type of pomegranate.

Comment: I don't think I'd call pale pink/white the normal color for pomegranates: https://www.google.com/search?q=pomegranate&tbm=isch but yes, all the other answers do say that there are varieties like this.

Answer (score -2):

it depends on how much the field is riched by minerals such as Iron. you know as the Iron amount increase in field you have a more red element object you have and the pomegrenate's fruit is not an exception

Comment: The red color in pomegranate is from anthocyanins, which contains no iron.